# JQuery Knob plugin - animate the values rising on read only knobs? - Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, input, jquery-knob

Here's a JSFiddle of the JQ Knob plugin which allows us to create dynamic stat wheels ("knobs")

**The knob inputs are pretty basic:**

```
<input type="text" data-width="150"
    data-fgColor="#6dc9ff"
    data-skin="tron"
    data-thickness=".1"
    data-angleOffset="180"
    data-readOnly="true"
    class="s2">
```

**And they look great:**

[image]

**JSFiddle (full 694 line source):**

http://jsfiddle.net/zfbud/

I've been trying to fix this plugin so that the knobs fill dynamically when populated via js:

```
$('.s1').val(97).trigger('change');
```

It seems like making that trigger add the value in an animated way rather than just snapping it should be a simple fix, but I keep breaking it, being pretty new to javascript.

**Can anyone tweak this (or already know of a fix) that makes this simple plugin animate it's change for read only knobs?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this question:

[Jquery Knob animate and change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315045/jquery-knob-animate-and-change-color?rq=1)